How can I type an array of class instances with different generics that all extend the same interface in TypeScript?
I have a Model constructor that looks like this:
interface Schema {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

export interface ModelField<T extends Schema = Schema> {
    name: keyof T;
    label: string;
}

class Model<T extends Schema = Schema> {

    protected fields: ModelField<T>[];

    constructor(fields: ModelField<T>[]) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    getFields(): ModelField<T>[] {
        return this.fields;
    }
}

I am implementing it to create models as:
interface ThingOneSchema extends Schema {
    baz: string;
    qux: string;
}

const ThingOne = new Model<ThingOneSchema>([
    { name: "foo", label: "Foo" },
    { name: "bar", label: "Bar" },
    { name: "baz", label: "Baz" },
    { name: "qux", label: "Qux" },
]);

interface ThingTwoSchema extends Schema {
    bam: string;
    boom: string;
}

const ThingTwo = new Model<ThingTwoSchema>([
    { name: "foo", label: "Foo" },
    { name: "bar", label: "Bar" },
    { name: "bam", label: "Bam" },
    { name: "boom", label: "Boom" },
]);

I then have an array of multiple models, all the same class, but with different generics that always extend the base interface:
export const models: Model[] = [
    ThingOne,
    ThingTwo,
];

However TS is complaining, and I'm not quite understanding why:
Type 'Model<ThingOneSchema>' is not assignable to type 'Model<Schema>'.
Type 'Schema' is missing the following properties from type 'ThingOneSchema': baz, qux

Type 'Model<ThingTwoSchema>' is not assignable to type 'Model<Schema>'.
Type 'Schema' is missing the following properties from type 'ThingTwoSchema': bam, boom

Is there a better way that to type this array of class instances, or use some inference trick without using Model<any>?
TS Playground Link

What is wrong with the code? it's working in typescript playground.

@HairyHandKerchief23 I think that's because the examples above didn't use T inside the class anywhere. I have updated the question to make it reproducable and added a TS Playground link above.

You're looking for heterogeneous collections which, by rights, requires existential types which TS doesn't have. If your class depends contravariantly on T (since it only uses keyof T) you could get away with defaulting to never instead of any as shown in this playground link. Or you could use the techniques mentioned in the q/a linked above (e.g., existential emulation as shown in this playground link).

Thank you for your time, and that's interesting, I've never seen this existential emulation pattern before. However using the emulation seems to not allow inference of the class properties. See this playground link (at the bottom). never and any both seem to work well enough in this case. I was just looking for a workaround to allow for inference of at least the base generic interface when looping the list of models.

See the linked q/a for how to use emulated existentials; you need to pass them callbacks. But you can’t “discover” the generic type arguments, they’re hidden now. Just like string doesn’t tell you which string, F<exists T> doesn’t tell you which T.
